# Aura:map multi line descritpion

Tags: aura, map

I have an `aura:map` with multiple point, and I wan't to have a multiple line descritpion as:

```
descritpion : 'Account Name : ' + mapInfo[it][3] + '\nContact : ' + mapInfo[it][4] + '\nprice : ' + mapInfo[it][5] + '\nExperience : ' + mapInfo[it][6]
```

But the `\n` are deleted and all the description are displayed on 1 line.
So, I have 2 question:

- Is it possible?
- If so, how can I do that?

Comment: What is `aura:map` ? Did you meant `<aura:attribute name="attrName" type="Map"/>` ?

Comment: no an `aura:map` like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/documentation) you can include `html` tags.

Try with `<br>` instead of `\n`